# C# ASP:NET MVC back end - Change from React Router v4 HashRouter to BrowserRouter results in 404 on refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, reactjs, react-router

I'm currently using `HashRouter` and it works really well. However I would like to be able to use the `#` on sub routes as well for linking to paragraphs. For example `/details#Summary`. As a benefit I will also get cleaner URLs and if needed I can get some [SEO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36623117/3850405).

Works and gives correct results on refresh/direct link.

```
<HashRouter>
    <App />
</HashRouter>
```

Works but gives 404 on refresh/direct link.

```
<BrowserRouter>
    <App />
</BrowserRouter>
```

[image]

I understand that the problem here is my routing in `.Net` and I need to change it. What do I need to do? I have a default route but it does not get hit.

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Comment: Do you have a controller called `Details`?  Because at the moment when you navigate to that URL, this is what MVC will be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First remove the standard `routes.MapRoute` that is shown above and then add this:

```
routes.MapRoute("Client", "{*anything}", defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional });
```

Now any route will render your default action.

**Optional:**

If you have a controller with attribute routing, example:

```
[RoutePrefix("Home")]
public HomeController : Controller {
    //GET Home/Index
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("Index")]
    public ActionResult Index() {
        return View(); 
    }
}
```

You also need to add:

```
routes.MapMvcAttributeRoutes();
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that when you change that, asp.net keeps trying to match a route from for details.

What you need to do is create a route that matches all paths, so that it returns the default one, eg: home/index

This is the route I use:

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "Default",
  "{*url}",
  new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" });
```

That will give control to the browser to math the paths after '/'